# Using PIP to install openpyxl for a user

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, openpyxl, python-module

I've written a script that will enable a user to have their weekly timesheet's filled out automatically and save it as a new excel spreadsheet.

I thought I would be able to just have the Openpyxl folder in the same directory as the script for it to import but it does not seem to work.

I have put together a bit of code based off a few other threads below to check for openpyxl before it imports. So I can hopefully have the ability to setup openpyxl. I intend to have this bit of code run during the import of the os, sys, time, datetime etc.

```
try:
    __import__('imp').find_module('openpyx')
    print('this worked')
except ImportError:
    pass
    print('')
    print('You do not have OpenpyXl installed - it will now install')
    print('')
```

I understand I should be using PIP ? So if I have the Openpyxl folder in the same directory as the script how can I point too it ? 
Would I need to change the sys path ?

This is how my code essentially starts out -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import openpyxl
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

FMT = '%H:%M'

print("")
print("Welcome to Timesheet Bot 1.0")
print ('\033[91m' + "I now will ask you a few questions about your work week." + '\033[0m')
time.sleep(3)

# Location of spreadsheet

file = str(input('Please drag and drop the spreadsheet here : '))
path = file
os.chdir(path)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('DC.xlsx')
FMT = '%H:%M'
sheet = wb['TIMESHEET']

# Name of the individual
print("")
name = str(input('What is your full name? '))
sheet['B9'] = name
```

Im still learning as I go so appreciate any guidance or reading that I should do to learn it.

Comment: If the `openpyxl` folder with all the source files is in the same directory you should be able to import it without installing it.

Comment: I downloaded it again and extracted it to make sure it was all there and still no luck.

Comment: mabye because of the typo? `find_module('openpyx')`

Comment: That was for an earlier test to make sure if it wasn’t finding the script it would run the other statement.

Comment: You do know there is a typo in your import?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to use `virtualenv`

1. First install `virtualenv` : `pip install virtualenv`
2. Move to the folder where the project resides make a
   `requirement.txt` file with all python dependencies like `openpyxl`
3. Start a virtual env by command `virtualenv venv --python=python3`
4. Activate the environment by `source venv/bin/activate`
5. Install all requirements by `pip install -r requirement.txt`
6. When you want to get out of the environment just use :
   `source venv/bin/deactivate`

Refer this: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Comment: I’m on OSX - so I’m guessing this will change a few steps. So I’ll essentially be able to do all this in script still ? Install the virtual env on the users Mac ?

Comment: Updated the answer for osx. You can install virtualenv on any machine and install the modules required.