# Why is it recommended to install openpyxl in a virtual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Multiple sources recommend that the openpyxl module be installed in a virtual environment including:

- https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-excel-tutorial
- [Using PIP to install openpyxl for a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924490/using-pip-to-install-openpyxl-for-a-user)

Why is this the recommendation for working with this module? What are the implications of installing the module on system instead?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use pip to install packages system-wide. You can easily break things because your system handles the system python installation, and does not follow what has been installed via pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you should install *everything* into a virtual environment.

System Python is for system-managed programs that may use Python. Messing with it can break them in subtle ways.

If you are not installing `openpyxl` via your OS's package manager, but are using `pip`, you should use `virtualenv` and never use `sudo` or administrative privileges on the machine for installing it.

Comment: There is no clear reason why it was emphasized in these materials that openpyxl **specifically** should be installed in a virtual environment. Installing other packages was mentioned without any suggestion to install those packages in virtual environments which is strange. But great, point taken and topic researched/understood. My colleague sent me this primer on Python virtual environments: [link](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/). It may be helpful if someone wanders here and wants additional information.